# Facebook Registration - Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I am using Register via Facebook for my website.

After a user authenticates via Facebook Login, I retrieve and store their email address and name (nothing else).

Is there some type of unique identifier that goes along with everyone's facebook account?
What if someone changes their email address on their Facebook account?

I've checked their docs but can't find anything to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for user id.  This is going to be unique for each facebook user and cannot change (unless some user deletes their facebook account and then goes in a registers a new facebook account)

Answer (score 0):

Every Facebook user has a unique 'userId'. This userId will never change.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/